# Why can't I access model if I initialize it inside method?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

a portion of ProfileController.java:

```
    public ModelAndView profilePage() {
        ...
        Map<String, Object> model = new BindingAwareModelMap();

        model.put("general", profileGeneralDTO);
        model.put("security", profileSecurityDTO);

        return new ModelAndView("profile/profile.html", "profile", model);
    }
```

how can I access `general` and `security` objects in a `th:object` directive at a thymeleaf template?

I can access them as `${general}` and `${secuity}` if I declare `model` at the method declaration:

```
    public ModelAndView profilePage(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            Map<String, Object> model
    ) {
        ...
//        Map<String, Object> model = new BindingAwareModelMap();

        model.put("general", profileGeneralDTO);
        model.put("security", profileSecurityDTO);

        return new ModelAndView("profile/profile.html", "profile", model);
    }
```

the `model` has the same `BindingAwareModelMap` class, but it works... why?

Comment: in the second you use what inside the profileGeneralDTO you don't use your model  map at all

Comment: Sorry, that was a wrong copy-paste... Of course it is "model" in the second code block as well..

Comment: Because you are using the wrong constructor of `ModelAndView`. You are using the one where you pass a model attribute to the model. So you are adding a map under the key `profile` to the model. Using `profile.general` works. Instead you want to use `new ModelAndView(new ModelAndView("profile/profile.html", model)`. The differerence is that the second has both `profile.general` and `general` in the model.

Comment: Thanks. But using ${profile.general} works for all directives except when I try to use it in a structure like th:object=“${profile.general}” -> th:field=“*{nickname}”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code samples are actually using the wrong constructor for [`ModelAndView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-). You are using the constructor to add a single element to the model. So you are actually adding the `Map` you want to use as the model, as an element to the model.

Using `${profile.general}` will work in your views.

However what you should be using is [the constructor with 2 arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) (a viewname and a map or model).

So instead of `new ModelAndView("profile/profile.html", "profile", model)` use `new ModelAndView("profile/profile.html", model)`.

**NOTE:** The second sample works due to the fact you are adding things to the implicit model and adding that model as a map to the model again. So in that situation both `${profile.general}` and `${general}` will work.

Comment: That makes sense, but is there a way to use ```${profile.general}``` in a ```th:object```? It works well if I use ```${profile.general.nickname}``` in a ```th:text``` but doesn't work if I use it in ```th:object``` and they try to use ```th:text="*{nickname}"```

Comment: As stated don't use the constructor with 3 arguments, use the 2 argument constructor instead. Then you don't need to go through those hoops. Else use `${profile}` as the `th:object` and `th:field="*{general.nickname}"`. Why would the map need to be the model object (not to be confused with the underlying model!).

Comment: I understand that and I made it work as I need. The question of "how to use ```profile.general``` in a ```th:object```"  was more like curiosity. Just to know if it is possible or not